# What are lunar sabbaths?

Tags: sabbath, sunday

I know about the 7th day Sabbath and I know about SUNday but I cant quite understand lunar Sabbaths. What are these and who observes them?

Comment: Why is this important? More context please.

Comment: Too lazy to answer but this [pro link](http://www.lunarsabbath.info/) and this [con link](http://www.eliyah.com/lunarsabbath.html) at first glace seem to provide an answer to "what".  [This link](http://www.lunarsabbath.com/lunar_sabbath_fellowships.htm) seems to give some "who" information. [This](http://www.therefinersfire.org/lunar_sabbath_myth.htm) states: "Many traditional and Messianic Jews and some Christians insist that the YHWH-commanded Seventh Day Sabbath is actually lunar", so it appears mostly Jews (i.e., fewer Gentile Christians).

Comment: Weren't they a heavy metal band?

Answer (score 1):

Lunar Sabbaths are an idea some groups - mostly Messianic Jewish branches - hold to that claim the Sabbath does not happen every 7 days, but on a cycle based upon the New Moon. There is an article that deals with them at http://csda-adventistchurch.to/lunar.html